# PYTHON TkInter - setting and accessing entry widget text as variable

Tags: python, tkinter

Ive tried reading as many articles about this as i can, but cannot find anything that helps me. In my code, i have created a class EntryWidget which has an entry widget amongst other things in it, and in my main class Controller for the app, i have created an instance of the class EntryWidget called self.entry. I am trying to write a method which will be a command for an ok button, which primarily takes the text from the entry widget and then manipulates it. this code is from the main class Controller:

```
     def ok(self):
         self.input = self.entry.get()
         self.command = ""
```

error:

```
     AttributeError: EntryWidget instance has no attribute 'get'
```

the idea is that text is entered, then the ok button is hit which calls this method. sorry if this has been asked before, but i have read the other responses and they dont help.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `EntryWidget` class doesn't subclass `Tkinter.Entry`, you will need to define `get()` method for your `EntryWidget` class. The error says that `self.entry` is a `EntryWidget` instance but does not contain `get()` method.

Comment: thankyou, youre absolutely right, it inherits from frame. how would i define the get method?

Comment: @user1710566 I am not sure what you are trying to do with the `get` method, but to simply define it in the `EntryWidget` class all you need to do is to put `def get(self): # do something you want` in your `WidgetEntry` class.

Comment: i would like to just get the text from the box as a string which i can  assign to a variable and use. would something like work:

    def get(self):
        input = entry.Tkinter.Entry.get()
        return input

Comment: @user1710566 without knowing how you defined entry I am not sure if that will work. Can you paste the code?

Comment: class EntryWidget(Frame):
    "the entry widget container"

    def __init__(self, master, parent):
        """creates a space for entry widget
        master - the top level window
        parent - the app object
        """
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.parent = parent
        self.ok = Button(self, text="OK", width=5, command = parent.ok)
        self.ok.pack()
        self.entrybox = Entry(self, width=50)
        self.entrybox.pack(side=RIGHT, pady=(0,10), padx=(5,5))
        self.label = Label(self, text="")
        self.label.pack()

Comment: @user1710566 it seems to me that `self.entry.entrybox.get()` is what you actually want instead of calling `self.entry.get()`.

Comment: doesnt throw me any errors now, i really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote myself a small function that allows the user to enter a value into a tkinter.Entry, and then function returns the user's input.

```
def getInput(title, message):
    class inputGUI(tkinter.Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
            self.title(title)
            self.l=tkinter.Label(self,text=message, width = 30, pady = 10, padx = 5).pack()
            self.e=tkinter.Entry(self, width = 30)
            self.e.pack()
            self.e.focus()
            self.gap=tkinter.Label(self,text="", width = 50, pady = 0, padx = 5).pack()
            self.b=tkinter.Button(self,text='Submit',command=self.cleanup, width = 20, pady = 10, padx = 5).pack()
            self.gap=tkinter.Label(self,text="", width = 30, pady = 0, padx = 5).pack()
        def cleanup(self):
            self.userInput=self.e.get()
            self.destroy()
    root = inputGUI()
    root.focus()
    root.wait_window(root)
    valueOut = root.userInput
    return valueOut
```

Note: I'm aware there is no entry validation, however this should be easy enough to add.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me if your class subclassed Entry, you could use all methods from Entry. Such as .get(). Or  define a  tk StringVar() and then use it's .get() and .set() methods.  You can think of an Entry Widget as a small tk Text widget so some things, such as delete( e.g. myEnt.delete(1.0,END) work the same.